# Numpy Sort 3D Array of Coordinates

Tags: python, numpy

I got a 3D array of rects' coordinates from [CRAFT text detector](https://github.com/fcakyon/craft-text-detector) that looks like this.

```
arr = np.array(
    [
        [
            [13.715625, 149.62498],
            [68.99374, 149.62498],
            [68.99374, 162.50937],
            [13.715625, 162.50937],
        ],
        [
            [22.44375, 96.84062],
            [64.8375, 96.84062],
            [64.8375, 111.80312],
            [22.44375, 111.80312],
        ],
        [
            [76.890625, 96.84062],
            [120.53125, 96.84062],
            [120.53125, 111.80312],
            [76.890625, 111.80312],
        ],
        [
            [83.54063, 122.609375],
            [102.24375, 122.609375],
            [102.24375, 135.49374],
            [83.54063, 135.49374],
        ],
        [
            [99.75, 124.6875],
            [150.04062, 124.6875],
            [150.04062, 137.57187],
            [99.75, 137.57187],
        ],
        [[133.0, 96.425], [176.225, 96.425], [176.225, 111.80312], [133.0, 111.80312]],
        [
            [189.3869, 97.28999],
            [232.66872, 96.73509],
            [232.85771, 111.47669],
            [189.57588, 112.03161],
        ],
        [
            [201.99374, 150.04062],
            [254.77812, 150.04062],
            [254.77812, 158.76874],
            [201.99374, 158.76874],
        ],
        [
            [208.64375, 8.728125],
            [248.95938, 8.728125],
            [248.95938, 21.6125],
            [208.64375, 21.6125],
        ],
        [
            [209.05937, 23.275],
            [254.3625, 23.275],
            [254.3625, 35.74375],
            [209.05937, 35.74375],
        ],
        [
            [218.86273, 71.343155],
            [253.87411, 70.50955],
            [254.11385, 80.5778],
            [219.10246, 81.41141],
        ],
    ],
)
```

Those are actually some parts of the texts detected by CRAFT after being sorted with this code:

```
boxes = prediction["boxes"]
idx = np.lexsort((boxes[:, 3][:, 1], boxes[:, 3][:, 0]))
sorted_pred = {
     "boxes": prediction["boxes"][idx],
     "boxes_as_ratio": prediction["boxes_as_ratios"][idx],
     "polys": prediction["polys"][idx],
     "polys_as_ratio": prediction["polys_as_ratios"][idx]
}
```

If we take a look at this credit card below:

[image: Credit Card]

The problem is that the text `Adrian W.` is placed first since it is the leftmost text on the card. How can we use Numpy sort such that the order of the detected text would be:

`HSBC..`, `world`, the card number from left to right `5183, 2301, 1234, 5678`, `valid date`, `Adrian W.`

which means that we sort the texts by using the y coordinate of the top-left point of each rect's and only sort by x if there are same y coordinates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> which means that we sort the texts by using the y coordinate of the
> top-left point of each rect's and only sort by x if there are same y
> coordinates?

Wouldn't the following give you the desired result?

```
 arr = sorted(arr, key=lambda x: (x[0][1], x[0][0]))
```

Then you can add `arr = np.array(arr)` to get a numpy array.

Comment: I'll try this and get back to you, but is there any way to get the indices out of the sorting process since I would require them to also sort the other arrays in the same generated order?

Comment: Do you mean top-level indices of the original array to get how rectangles got permuted? Then the following might give you that  `l = [(item, i) for i, item in enumerate(list(arr))]
arr = np.array(sorted(l, key=lambda x: (x[0][0][1], x[0][0][0])))`

Comment: It works, thank you so much for the help, appreciate it! :D